# How to determine if a parachain runtime migration is too big?

Tags: parachain, storage, migration, try-runtime, pov

I want to write runtime storage migration for our parachain. This time it will scan large storage maps with more than 10k entries. This may results in very large PoV block size. I'm wondering what the limitation is, and how I can check the PoV block size created by the migration.

In the past, I have the impression that after running `try_runtime`, it prints the PoV block size. But it looks like the log was removed in the recent version. It only prints the weights now.

Comment: relevant issue here :)
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/12195